# about:blank page after running my ASP.NET web app using Ctrl + F5

Tags: asp.net

my web application open about:blank page when i tried to run it using Ctrl+F5.

i am using VS2008 C# ASP.NET web application.

also i set a start up page to the my project.

please what is this page?and how to overcome it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you running IE8 for the first time via visual studio? Try browsing IE8 to google.com and running the initialization that pops up if so.

Seems your not alone: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/473541/start-without-debugging-opens-blank-page-ie8-first

If that doesn't fix it try making another browser (firefox?) your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have an issue with your server. If you look at you rsolution then, choose property pages, check that the Start Options are correct, especially if you are not using the "default web server" (this refers to vs2010 but I assume it is similar).

I would choose 'Use Current Page" if it isn't selected.